# Dialog not displaying propagated model data

Tags: data-binding, internationalization, sapui5

In my UI5 application, I have an *i18n.properties* file with keys and values:

```properties
#XMSG:
qty=Quantity
```

And I'm using this property value in a dialog box as title

```js
onUpdateDialog: function() {
  var that = this;
  var dialog = new Dialog({
    title: "{i18n>qty}",
    // ...,
  });
  dialog.open();
},
```

But when I run my application, the dialog box title is not getting displayed:

[image]

When I use text values from i18n property file somewhere else it's getting displayed.

Comment: For confirmation dialogs, you can also use [sap.m.MessageBox](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.MessageBox) instead. Here are [some samples](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.MessageBox%20) and [UX guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/message-box/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManagedObjects, that are created by the application code imperatively outside of the framework-managed features (Such creating an instance of `sap.m.Dialog` in a Controller code without using the [API `loadFragment`](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/04129b2798c447368f4c8922c3c33cd7)), have to be added to the model delegation chain manually in order to make use of the propagated models.

In order to do so, add the created instance to the parent's [`<dependents>` aggregation](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Element#methods/addDependent). E.g.:

```js
this.getView().addDependent(myDialog); // myDialog is now aware of the "i18n" model
```

From API Reference:

> Special aggregation `dependents` is connected to the lifecycle management and databinding, but not rendered automatically and can be used for popups or other dependent controls or elements. This allows the definition of popup controls in declarative views and enables propagation of model and context information to them.

Comment: @tarzanbappa You can bind the title dynamically via `myDialog.bindProperty("title", { ... })`. Check out the [API reference of `bindProperty`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindProperty).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use texts in the controller you need to fetch the text first, like so:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("qty")
```

this will be the dialog inside the dialog, so declare a that before the dialog and change this to that..

```
var that = this;
that.getOwnerComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("qty")
```

Hope this solves your issue..

Comment: it gives 
`assignment.controller.js?eval:500 Uncaught TypeError: that.getResourceBundle is not a function`

Comment: Hi Tarzanbappa,

Ofocurse it does, my bad :-)

It's because getResourceBundle lives in my BaseController..

this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("qty") is the correct code (or should be)

Corrected this in previous answer

Comment: Calling `getText` retrieves the text from the bundle which can be assigned to the `title` property and thus displaying the text (+1 for that) but unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue with the resource binding (`"{i18n>qty}"`) not working.

Answer (score 0):

At the point of opening the Dialog, it doesn't know the i18n model. You need to provide the model to the dialog by calling `dialog.setModel(this.getModel('i18n'), 'i18n')` before opening the dialog.